# How to update a Jquery calendar with a JS variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement this [jQuery Calendar](https://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Clean-jQuery-Date-Time-Picker-Plugin-datetimepicker.html) into my website. I've got the calendar running, and everything works.

I want to be able to alter the date in the calendar when a user pushes one of four buttons:

- 1 hour
- Tomorrow
- 1 week
- 2 weeks

When a user pushes a button I would like the calendar to change the date accordingly. The calendar has the option called `startDate` that I can use for the purpose - but I can't seem to trigger it.

The content of `val` = `f.x. 2020-03-07 10:02`

```js
$.datetimepicker.setLocale('da');

$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
  dayOfWeekStart: 1,
  lang: 'da',
  inline: true,
  scrollMonth: false,
  timepicker: false,
  startDate: new Date(document.getElementById('timeForAlert').value),
  onSelectDate: function() {
    userHasChosen();
  },
  onSelectTime: function() {
    userHasChosen();
  }
});

$('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker({
  format: 'Y-d-m'
});

$('.some_class').datetimepicker();

function makeReadable(val) {
  var mydate = new Date(val);
  var hour = document.getElementById('hour').value;
  var minute = document.getElementById('minutes').value;
  var str = mydate.getFullYear() + '-' + ("0" + (mydate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ("0" + mydate.getDate()).slice(-2) + ' ' + hour + ':' + minute + ':00';
  return str;
}

function oneday(val) {
  document.getElementById('datetimepicker').value = val;
  document.getElementById('timeForAlert').value = makeReadable(val);
  $.datetimepicker();
  stopReload();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution asking in another forum.

The documentation for this script is terrible !

Here is what we found:

```
$(function() {
    $('#dt').datetimepicker({
        dayOfWeekStart: 1,
        lang: 'da',
        inline: true,
        scrollMonth: false,
        timepicker: false,
        startDate: new Date()
    });
});

$('#btn').click(function() {
    $('#dt').datetimepicker({
        value: new Date('2020-01-01T00:00:00Z')
    });
});
```

Run this from a button with `id` = `btn` and you're set